# Wordpress Plugin wp-filebase

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Updated wordpress to the latest version now having an issue with the plugin wp-filebase (worked fine for years). Have tried the standard wordpress troubleshooting of disabling all the plugins and re-installing. Using tag=browser to display a collapsed tree of files. When you click on the folder to expand, it does nothing. The error generated is:

jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:formatted:1831Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

```
    function ca(a) {
    var b = ba.split("|")
      , c = a.createDocumentFragment();
    if (c.createElement)
        while (b.length)
            c.createElement(b.pop());
    return c
}
```

Thanks